# How to make spotify ipad app login screen Xcode

Tags: xcode, animation, spotify

How would i make a view in xcode like the spotify login window with images moving like a carousal in the background

[image: image of login app]

Comment: What constitutes as a real question then?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like they have many image views with both alpha and translation animations. As the images move left, the image view's alpha decreases. The translation animation is the image moving left. It also looks like there is a CATransform3D transform applied to the UIImageViews like this:

```
#import <Quartzcore/Quartzcore.h>
---------------------------------
UIImageView *albumCoverImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"Black Eyed Peas Album"]];
CALayer *layer = albumCoverImageView.layer;
CATransform3D perspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
perspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -1000;
perspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(perspectiveTransform, 45.0f * M_PI / 180.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
layer.transform = perspectiveTransform;
```

In summary:

- Slow translation animation going from right to left of album covers
- Alpha (opacity) of images decreases as the image goes from right to left
- Perspective transform using CATransform3D

Hope this helps!